# Difference between self.variable and _variable,about KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, key-value-observing

The first image is using self.name to change,and the second image using _name to change.it should be the same result,but the second one outputs nothing.why?

[image]

[image]

here is the code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface kvo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation kvo

- (void)change
{
    _name = @"b";
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) kvo *a1;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.a1 = [[kvo alloc] init];
    _a1.name = @"a";
    [self.a1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [_a1 change];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"1");
}
```

the difference is `self.name` and `_name` in the change method

Edit:it's not the same question as "What's the difference between _variable & self.variable in Objective-C? [duplicate]", i know that's about the getter method and setter method,and my question is that why setter method fires the KVO and the `_name = @"b"` does not fire the KVO.

Comment: Please post code as text, not an xcode screenshot.  Text is easier to cut/paste and otherwise work with.

Comment: Arun,i think that's another question.

Comment: by using `_name` you are bypassing kvo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get KVO notification only when you are accessing the instance variable through a property. Direct setting of instance variable will not invoke KVO notification.

Here the first case, you are setting the name by

```
self.name = @"b";
```

In fact this will call the property setter method `setName:` which internally sends the KVO notifications `didChangeValueForKey`. Actually the notifications are fired by the calling of setter method..

In the second case

```
_name = @"b";
```

You are directly setting the instance variable, without a property setter method. So the KVO notification will not be fired.

If you want you can fire the notification by yourself

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"name"];

_name = @"b";

[self didChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
```

But i dont think it requires, set the variable using the property. That will do everything for you.
Read more about [KVO notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE)

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive key-value observing notifications for a property, three things are required:

**Step 1 :** The observed class must be key-value observing compliant for the property that you wish to observe.

**Step 2 :** You must register the observing object with the observed object, using the method `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`.

**Step 3 :** The observing class must implement `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`.

[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html)